# Expanding Data Range based on variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to get the data range of my table to update based on a varialbe.  My code is:

```
Sub outputupdatescale()  
Dim workdayCol As String  
    Worksheets("Summary").Activate  
    workdayCol = Cells(2, "F").Value  

    Sheets("Output").Select
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 9").Activate
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "='2014 actual'!$C$54:workdayCol&54"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = "='2014 actual'!$C$56:workdayCol&56"
End Sub
```

However I get a 1004 error on running.

I know the issue is with how I am inputting my variable I just can't think of what to try next.  Also I assume there is a far easier way to do it so would be very grateful of any help

Comment: Have you tried `"='2014 actual'!$C$54:" & workdayCol & "54"`?

Comment: You want a code that resize your table base on a cell.value? Example if I type D10 in the cell your table goes ffrom A1 to D10?

Comment: @findwindow has it. When using a variable, you need to "pull it out" of the formula.  If you notice, the `"` after the colon is followed by an `&` which allows you to then put some variable name, follow it with another linking `&` and finish the formula.

Comment: Thanks, knew I was being silly

Comment: Thank you, knew it was something simple