# Replace RC Formula Value with Variable VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following that is placing a simple Vlookup into a cell.

`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-25],[MasterFood.xlsx]Sheet1!C1:C6,6,0),0)"`

I'm needing to replace the `-25` with the a variable (called LastColumn) which has already been calculated as the column number will change everytime the program is run. The full part of the code is below

```
Dim LastColumn As Integer

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells) > 0 Then
    LastColumn = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    Cells(1, LastColumn + 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ORDER"
End If

Cells(2, LastColumn + 1).Select

'Define Categories


For z = 2 To RowCount - 1

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-25],[MasterFood.xlsx]Sheet1!C1:C6,6,0),0)"
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Next
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: Please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33677576/expanding-data-range-based-on-variable?noredirect=1#comment55128843_33677576).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[" & LastColumn & "],[MasterFood.xlsx]Sheet1!C1:C6,6,0),0)"
```